# What is the most appropriate way to use "caption" HTML element in today's modern way?

Tags: html, css, image, templates, caption

Are they used with CSS? (non-tables?)

How are they used?

Please give examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS caption-side property is used to specify where a caption will be positioned with regards to the table (i.e. above or below the table).

> ```
> Syntax:   caption-side: <value> Possible Values:  
>
> * top
> * bottom
> * inherit
> ```
>
> Initial Value:    Top Applies to:
>     Tables with a caption Inherited:    Yes
>   Media:    Visual Example:
>
> caption {   caption-side: bottom;
>   width: auto;   text-align: left;   }

```
<style type="text/css">
caption {
  caption-side: bottom;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  }
</style>
<table border="1">
  <caption>This is the caption</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>Try changing the values to see the effect it has on the position of the caption.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Note:</b> If this is not working, your browser might not support the caption-side property. At the time of writing, browser support for the caption-side property was limited.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This element should be used for
>   providing a short heading for the
>   table; it should not be used to
>   provide a description of the table’s
>   structure, as you might do with the
>   table summary attribute.

The `caption` element provides a means for labeling the following `table`’s content in a visual manner (unlike the `table`’s summary attribute, which is non-visible). It has one element-specific attribute, `align`, which is very rudimentary and not entirely supported (it’s also deprecated, so it should generally be avoided).

The `caption` element can only be used once per `table` and must immediately follow the `table` start tag.

While the caption element seems like the most appropriate markup for labeling a `table`, and indeed its intention is to `label` a data table in much the same way that you might provide a caption for a picture in a book. However, in most printed media, captions for illustrations, images and tables usually occur after the item, whereas the caption element comes before the table. A combination of poor styling options for `caption` with CSS and poor alignment support has led many people instead choose to precede tables with heading elements 1-6 (for example, an `h3` element). This makes it easier for some people using assistive technology, such as screen readers, to jump from heading to heading in the document (there are ways to navigate by heading and also to bring up a list of headings on a page). However, it should be noted that a heading is really intended to indicate the content of the whole section following the heading, right up to wherever the next heading is, rather than one discrete part of the page, as the `caption` is. The `caption` element is the correct markup to identify a `table`, then, but don’t be surprised if you see people using headings instead.

**Example**

Here’s a table caption that provides a visual summary and heading all in one:

```
<table border="1">
  <caption>Interest Rates for Young Saver Accounts</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Account Type</th>
    <th>Interest Rate</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smart</td>
    <td>From 2%</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Young Saver</td>
    <td>From 1.6%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```